# Getting "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'" error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df['Mass']=df['Mass'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')).astype(float)
```

Comment: Apparently `df['Mass']` contains floats and not strings. Also look up how to ask a question and welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Google python casting

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `x` type is float, but you can use replace only over string. A cast should do it:

```
df['Mass']=df['Mass'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('$', '').replace(',', '')).astype(float)
```

Comment: I'm glad that helped you. If it solved the problem please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: That gets rid of the error message but there will never be a `$` in `str(x)` if x is a float, so there's no point in replacing anything. If he expected a dollar sign in there, there's something else wrong.

Comment: @LukasNeugebauer the column Mass could have mixed datatypes entries combining both strings and floats. This is certainly not a good practice but Pandas does allowes it. For instance, this will work in pandas: `df = pd.DataFrame([1.0, 2.0, '3$'])`